# Is IF obligatory to be followed by ELSE

Tags: php, html, web

I am not sure if the IF must be followed by ELSE like in my example above or if IF can be used alone like it is without any ELSE. 
Will the page show to anyone if there is no ELSE? I am a beginner...

```
<?php
$rank = $user["rank"];
if ($rank != 'ADMIN'){
    header('Location: get_the_he.._out.php');
    exit();
    }
else {

?>
<html>
<head><title>Show Page</title></head>

<body>

Here we show page if user is admin

</body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It must not, you can have an IF without the ELSE or ELSEIF part.

Comment: `else` is completely optional.

Comment: Thanks amigo. Please add it as answer for future user reference when comming from search engines

Comment: Really? I did searched using Stackoverflow's search engine and after reading 2 pages I gived up

Comment: To be sure the script will not continue I just must be sure to set the exit(); after header location? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO. There is no need to have an ELSE with an IF. However you then need to make sure that the script will not continue after the IF, as you are doing here :)

Comment: To be sure the script will not continue I just must be sure to set the exit(); after header location? Thanks a lot

Comment: David are you here ?

Comment: To be sure the script will not continue after IF I just must set the exit(); after header location as I am doing in my example is that correct?

Comment: @coderminator Yes you are right, the exit handles everything. Sometimes we just want to add additional processing according to some condition then continue on with the rest of the script. In that case we do not need the exit or an ELSE. Beware though, coding like this can result in emergent bugs when you or someone else alters the script and removes, or bypasses the exit(). Better not to rely on the exit() and use a branch to an exit function or procedure. Make your code future proof.